# C++ convert char[] from network to host order and assign to unsigned int

Tags: c++, char, byte, unsigned-integer, endianness

I have an array of characters that are in network byte order. I'm trying to convert the characters stored in indices [4-7] into host order and assign it to an unsigned int. I have the following function:

```
unsigned int parse_num_bytes(char buf[]){ 
  unsigned int num_bytes = ((unsigned int)buf[7] << 24) | ((unsigned int)buf[6] << 16) | ((unsigned int)buf[5] << 8) | (unsigned int)buf[4];
  return num_bytes;
}
```

From GDB (acutally LLDB because I'm on a mac) I can see that the operation generates the correct result, but after assignment, the value is wrong:

```
   81
   82   unsigned int parse_num_bytes(char buf[]){
   83     unsigned int num_bytes = ((unsigned int)buf[7] << 24) | ((unsigned int)buf[6] << 16) | ((unsigned int)buf[5] << 8) | (unsigned int)buf[4];
-> 84     return num_bytes;
   85   }
(lldb) p num_bytes
(unsigned int) $0 = 4294967170
(lldb) p ((unsigned int)buf[7] << 24) | ((unsigned int)buf[6] << 16) | ((unsigned int)buf[5] << 8) | (unsigned int)buf[4]
(unsigned int) $1 = 2434
```

For clarification, `2434` is the correct value.

Here is where I generate the network ordering (in a server application):

```
return_buf[4] = index & 0xff;
return_buf[5] = (index >> 8) & 0xff;
return_buf[6] = (index >> 16) & 0xff;
return_buf[7] = (index >> 24) & 0xff;
```

And from GDB I can show you the value of index (it's an `unsigned int`)

```
   142    return_buf[4] = index & 0xff;
   143    return_buf[5] = (index >> 8) & 0xff;
   144    return_buf[6] = (index >> 16) & 0xff;
-> 145    return_buf[7] = (index >> 24) & 0xff;
   146
   147    in_file.close();
   148    Rio_writen(connfd, return_buf, MAXLINE);
(lldb) p index
(unsigned int) $0 = 2434
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess your `char` type is signed, so it can contain negative values. Those don't convert well to `unsigned int`.

You might want to use `unsigned char` for your buffer type.